# Would Fishmen Wear Corsets?

Tags: humanoid, clothing, fish

Corsets are a useful piece of clothing. They have a variety of uses, including shaping the body

This functionality can clearly work in mammals and other cases where the spine is in the back, however I am unsure of if it will also work for fish

Unlike mammals, fish have much more muscle in their body, to the point that often the spine is almost closer to the middle of the body than to the back

Given this, could a fish-like humanoid (that being a creature with humanoid arms and legs on a fish-like torso) shape their bodies with a corset as mammals can?

Comment: I actually wonder if any clothing would do underwater. A clothed fish gets More Drag than an unclothed one, thus any clothes inventor would have more chances to Get Eaten by a Something Fierce than the other folk of theirs. I think that not even mermen that have breasts as females would desire any clothing except bare minimum, just for them to not get too clumsy - and a woman in a corset is seriously restricted in movement.

Comment: -1 This is [the fourth "Can X wear corsets?"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A75161+is%3Aq+corset) question you've asked. What about the three previous questions (lizards, birds, frogs...) were insufficient to give you an answer to this question?

Comment: @JBH lizards, birds, and frogs are all tetrapods, not fish

Comment: @JBH are related yet distinct questions not allowed on this stack?

Comment: @MS --- Given that all the queries focus on the *clothing choices* of a variety of animal shaped sophonts, none of the questions after the first are truly "distinct". First of all, they're all story based: they ask what an individual or group of individuals would do. That's off topic here. Second, they all relate to a humanoid with some other kind of animal characteristics wearing an article of human clothing. One answer serves for all as the querent is simply reasking the same question when they should have gotten sufficient opinions from the first query. Lastly, all of these (cont)

Comment: (cont) questions are inherently opinion based. I don't generally mind opinion based queries, but when you ask the same opinion based question four times, it's time to stop.

Comment: Yes, it'd probably be designed to be smooth and make them more aerodynamic, in order to assist swimming.

Comment: @Vesper apparently not as much as you might think if you watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCe5Kht9a2U (I'm taking the creator's word for it, having zero personal experience.)

Comment: @elemtilas Firstly, while the questions are nominally about clothing choices, the real issue is to do with their physical anatomy and whether it allow for certain clothing to work correctly. Secondly, saying that these questions are just about 'a humanoid with some other kind of animal characteristic' is ridiculously oversimplified: Saying corsetry doesn't work on an inflexible ribcage says absolutely nothing about whether a mostly muscular torso would work

Comment: Your questions are *literally* about clothing choice --- would they do X. Leaving that aside, you provide insufficient information about the anatomy of the people in question. Still, the main issue remains: what is there about the answers to your initial question that you can't extrapolate to other kinds of people? These other queries, and a million more potential questions, are formal duplicates.

Comment: @elemtilas If I had asked a single question about how corsets might interact with any and every non-mammalian ribcage type, would you vote to close that for lacking focus?

Comment: If this is truly different from the previous, how are the manipulative limbs different? With no description of how the fish folk can manipulate their environment there is probably a default assumption they are humanoid. With the assumption they are humanoid this is not asking anything new.

Comment: You're not asking how the corset interacts. You're asking whether fishmen would wear corsets or not. I never said your questions "lacked focus". I'm saying that your questions are functional duplicates and are story based. By now, you should be able to extrapolate functionality to any body type. You should also know not to ask questions about what individuals or groups of people would do.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going presage my answer with that I am a great fan of Corsets and my Wife owns several ones, including some proper, steel boned corsets.

So, suffice to say - I'm not biased against Corsets.

I'm Frame challenging the opening line 'Corsets are a useful piece of clothing' - Apart from purely aesthetic purposes (and lord knows I love the look of a Corset) - there is very little useful about Corsets.

I've known some people who have had posture issues or use them as a training tool to artificially restrict movement/Breath - but that's about it. None of which I feel has any translation into an undersea Fishman.

With a Fish/human hybrid - you could *maybe* make an argument about artificially inducing a coke-bottle type affect for increased efficiency through the water, however - I'm not sure that would work - afterall, I'm not a fluid dynamicist. My feelings is that the hips/tail area would still bulge out which would mitigate any slight improvement a Corset would make.

Add to that - the reduction in Mobility/breathing would unlikely be offset by the supposed gains this would hace.

TL;DR - Corsets don't have any practical purposes other than making good looking ladies into jaw-droppingly stunning ladies and so apart from an aesthetic argument (Fishmen probably look good in Corsets - if that's your thing) - then no.

Comment: While I will agree that modern corsets are used for the aesthetic and can be used as a posture tool, I have to disagree on account of their original usage.

Historically, in their original time period, corsets were used for bust support, basically fulfilling the same role as modern bras do. Tight lacing, which impacts breathing and movement, is a relatively modern thing for the working class and in history was only done by those who could afford to not work.

Comment: Someone who is working could do their work in a corset if it was being worn correctly for their activity. Tight lacing is not the way that most corsets were used by working people in history.

Comment: A minor quibble: for some dress designs, a corset is the only method for holding the dress/skit on the body. However, a perfectly valid argument could be made that, as it's only an aesthetic, it's not needed as there are plenty of ways to keep the dress in place that don't require a corset.

Answer (score 3):

### They won't bother

Fish don't have breasts, and nor do they inhale, enhancing those breasts within corsets.

With your previous similar question regarding frogs, at least there was a sexually dimorphic feature (the absence of a vocal sac) that you could go all interspecies-BBC-version-Lizzie Bennet with.

With fish?
No.

The equivalent would be enhancing some sexually dimorphic feature that fish do have. Maybe making a girls fins a brighter yellow.

Answer (score 0):

No, fishmen would not wear corsets, and there are many reasons why. Firstly, it would be counterproductive towards movement. In order to swim, fish need to be able to be flexible, especially around their spine. With a corset restricting spine movement, your fishmen would have a hard time moving.

Second, a corset would restrict breathing. A lot of depictions of mermen/fishmen show them as having gills at their neck, but realistic mermen would probably have their gills on their chest as it's closer to their lungs and more realistic towards actual fish gill placement. If the mermen had gills on their chests, a corset would prevent them from breathing, not to mention that restricted movement would mean less water flowing around the body and therefore even less oxygen.

Finally, fish do not have breasts. I doubled checked this, so that question is now in my search history forever, but I digress. Fishmen would have no need for corsets because corsets (generally) are used to either act as a bra or just make breasts look bigger, neither of which apply to fish.

So for a variety a reasons, **no, your fishmen would not wear corsets.**